# C# simple program slow

Tags: c#, performance, windows-8, windows-10

I have a simple program written in C# and I ran it in two laptops same specs but one has Windows 8 and the other has Windows 10 and I measure the time in milliseconds and get the difference between the start and the end but in windows 8 it takes approx 1k milliseconds while in windows 10 it takes approx 15k milliseconds. Why this huge difference?

This is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            Console.WriteLine(milliseconds);
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
                if(i%10000==0)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            long milliseconds2 = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            Console.WriteLine(milliseconds2);
            Console.WriteLine("Diff " + (milliseconds2-milliseconds));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are both operating systems 64 bit? Do they both have the same version of .Net installed?

Comment: I would guess you are actually measuring the Console output speed.

Comment: Have you tried them just once? Or measure these times as an average of multiple runs?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes both are 64 bit with the same .Net version

Comment: @TaW you are correct

Comment: @WaqasShabbir this is an average for multiple runs

Comment: Why does this matter to you? What kind of real program writes that many lines to the console?

Comment: Please use https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet for benchmarking, rather than `DateTime.Now` (and update your question with the results). Are both laptops plugged into power? Are both configured to use 100% of CPU (check to be sure, this is a common issue in Win 10)? Are both the exact same CPU and RAM? Are both running only this program?

Comment: @mjwills it matters because if a simple code is running this slow compared to windows 8 imagine what happens for my other programs must do some data processing and need to find solution for this ... the answer is yes for all your questions in the next comment

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt but: Your code effectively does nothing. Your measurement is therefore totally meaningless. Put some typical workload in the loop and then you may get more useful results. My guess: The will not be a consistent result let alone any difference to worry about

Comment: @TaW I have macros and programs which do data analysis and they are more complicated and there also a huge difference which ends in 15 min in windows 8 takes min 3 hours to finish in windows 10

Comment: If that is so then there must be some explanation. But this test will not help you find it.